# Simulating touch screen events with separate application

Tags: events, touch, simulate

I'm developing a wireless HID Bluetooth device that works like a keyboard, on both Android and iOS.
I want to also develop an app that takes these keyboard input and simulates touch events in other applications (without changing the code to these applications).

For example, if a user uses my device to click on the X key, it will simulate a touch in certain coordinates in any application that is currently running.

Is that possible (either for iOS and/or Android)?

Comment: Sounds like a security risk... what is to prevent your app (or someone else's) for simulating touchs to dial to a toll number?

Comment: Yeah, I figured security might be an issue. Still, is there no way around it? Can't the user approve the assigned control, or something of that sort?